# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type , but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what I am trying to do. I don't understand Why it is expecting an enumerable list.

AddressController.cs

```
public ActionResult ShowAddresses(List<Address> ReturnAddresses)
    {
        ShowAddressViewModel viewModel = new ShowAddressViewModel() { Addresses = ReturnAddresses, Message = "New" };
return PartialView("_ShowAddr", viewModel);
```

}

ShowAddressViewModel.cs

```
public class ShowAddressViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

_ShowAddr.cshtml

```
@model PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<form>
<div class="addressBlock">
<table id="AddressTable">
    @{int i = 0;}
     @{PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel AddrModel = Model;}
    @foreach (var item  in AddrModel.Addresses)
    {
        <tr id = "@(i)">
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Address1)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Address2)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].City)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].State)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Zip)
            </td>
        </tr>
        @(i++)
    }
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

edit

Call from Another partial view's java script

```
$.ajax(url, {
            data: { ReturnAddresses : InboundAddresses },
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //Populate the form values
                // Start Dialog Code
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');
                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.html(data);
                $myWindow.dialog({
                    title: 'Select an address',
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto'
                });
                $myWindow.show();
                $myWindow.dialog("open");
                // End Dialog Code

                $('#AddressTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    alert('You clicked row ' + ($(this).index()));
                });
                addAddress(Addresses, Message)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#Message').val('Kaboom!!! (The call blew up...#thatsucks)');
                alert('The Dialog Box call failed...Sorry :(');
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Error in '/PSPOC' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  


Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +383
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +625
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +138
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727120
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +727076
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044
```

Comment: Where's the `POST` action code?

Comment: It looks correct to me... are you sure that `_ShowAddr.cshtml` is the only view you are passing the `ShowAddressViewModel` to?

Comment: @neoistheone Post has the url to call the controller method ShowAddress as shown in controller code above.

Comment: I am using ShowAddressViewModel for another external service call from another partial view's javascript which returns a JSON wrapped around ShowAddressViewModel

Comment: This may be offtopic, but can I ask, why you are going ad absurdum by using ant incrementing int value in a foreach loop, insted of just incrementing the id?

Comment: Yes, that was old code. I made a change after that but even if I remove all the code in that partial view, I still got that error.

Comment: Found a solution. 

Thanks a lot for helping. The solution is unrelated to any of the above. But, your comments help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In _ShowAddr.cshtml you don't need to index the List.  The Model is PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel so you should simply be able to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Addresses)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@item.Address1</td>
    <td>@item.Address2</td>
    <td>@item.City</td>
    <td>@item.State</td>
    <td>@item.Zip
  </tr>
}
```